# Passport.js - store information in session

Tags: node.js, session, express, passport.js

I currently have a mongoose/express/passportjs application that I can successfully log in and out with. However, only the user ID is stored in the session. I'd like the store the whole user object.

Here is the code I use:

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user._id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(_id, done) {
  done(null, { _id: _id });
});
```

Works great, here is why I tried to serialize the entire user:

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user._id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user);
});
```

However, it doesn't store any session with that.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This isn't really a direct answer to your question, but why is your deserializeUser method using { _id: _id } for the callback? Normally you would use a Mongoose query in that method to lookup the object from the database based on the _id that's passed in.

Answer (score 1):

In `serializeUser` you need to pass in the entire user to `done`:

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user);
});
```